# Dimension of the image of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

So the question asks:

Verify if the image of the linear map $T : \mathbb{R}^6 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ given by left multiplication by A= 
$$\begin{bmatrix}6 & 0 &2 & 2& 3& 4\\0 & -1 & 4 & 5&6 & 7\\6 & -1 & 6 & 7& 9& 11\end{bmatrix}$$

is two dimensional or not.

So so far I have the rref of the matrix is

$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 &1/3 & 1/3& 1/2& 2/3\\0 & 1 & -4 & -5&-6 & -7\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0& 0& 0\end{bmatrix}$$

and the im(T)=span{[1,0,1/3,1/3,1/2,2/3],[0,1,-4,-5,-6,-7]}
$$\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\1/3 \\ 1/3\\1/2\\2/3\end{bmatrix}$$
$$\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 1 \\ -4 \\-5\\-6 \\ -7\end{bmatrix}$$

So I think the the image is two dimensional, right? 
Since dim(kerT) + dim(imT)=dim($\mathbb{R}^6$) and since the image is 2, does it mean that the kernel of the linear map must be 4?

Comment: Yes to all of your questions.

Comment: The image isn't the span of the vectors given in your sketch. The image is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$!!!

Answer (score 2):

The image of T is the column space of A;

so since the RREF for A has two leading 1's, $\dim(\text{image}(T))=\dim(\text{col}(A))=2$.

A basis for the image of T is given by the columns of A corresponding to the leading 1's,

and the two vectors you have listed above give a basis for the row space of A.

You are correct that $\text{nullity}(T)=\dim(\ker(T))=6-2=4$.